# facebook error function response is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        $.ajax({

            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
            type: 'GET',
            data:'grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id="done"&client_secret="done"&fb_exchange_token="done"',  
            success: (function (response) {  alert(reponse);      })
        });    testAPI();
    }
```

my ajax query successfully pass the data: url: but gives error on function response

> Uncaught ReferenceError: reponse is not defined

```
$.ajax.success
c.extend.ajax.w.onreadystatechange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use the `response` variable instead of `reponse`, which is not defined:

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
    $.ajax({

        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&fb_exchange_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}',
        type: 'GET'
        success: function (response) {  
            alert(response);
        }
    });    
    testAPI();
}
```

Also, fix your call, because you are sending an incorrect request. Furthermore, replace the values between the `{}` with the actual values.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

still says

Comment: As you are not saying what you are trying to do it's quite difficult to help you. I think you should not pass the `data` property for a GET request. Changed my answer. You need to replace the values in `{}` with the actual values...

Comment: done thanx. i was getting long term user acess token of facebook client side. i did it thanks

Comment: can you also tell me how to get long term user acess token using c sharp and facebookAPI dll